# JQuery googlemap plugin language change issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-markers

I'm using `jquery.googlemap.js` (https://github.com/Tilotiti/jQuery-Google-Map) to generate a map given an address.

It does its work properly but I'm unable to change the map language:

```
<div id="map_1" style="width: 300px; height: 300px;"></div>
<script>
$('#map_1').googleMap({
 type: 'ROADMAP',
 langage: 'it' //(or italian or italiano, or whatever doesn't work)
});
$('#map_1').addMarker({
  address: 'just an address' // Postale Address
});
</script>
```

In the snippet above the type and all the other params work.
Yet, I point out that the param `langage`is properly spelled and you will see it when you check the JS object in `jquery.googlemap.js`.
Out of desperation I tried also with `language`but of course it doesn't work.

Comment: Looking at the demo's source: http://tilotiti.github.io/jQuery-Google-Map/ they supply the `langage` parameter on the `$("#map").addWay` method. try supplying `langage: 'it'` on your `addMarker({/* ... */})` method params

Comment: I tried with it, ita, italian, italiano, it doesn't work :(

Comment: not on the `googleMap` function like your snippet. move it to the `addMarker` function

Comment: the list of codes you can pass to the geocoder API is here: https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#languagesupport so `'it'` is correct. i think you are passing it in the wrong place.

Comment: So this is my snippet but still doesn't work:

```$('#map_1').googleMap({
 type: 'ROADMAP'
});
$('#map_1').addMarker({
  address: 'just an address', // Postale Address
 langage: 'it'
});```